# Are there any JBoss internal cron jobs that runs every 24 hours?

Tags: java, postgresql, jboss, jboss5.x, jta

Does JBoss AS 5.1 have any internal jobs that run every 24 hours?
We have an enterprise application connected to two postgresql databases (on one database server) that hangs every 24 hours for exactly 30 min. 
Example:

day 1: blocked 10:00 am - 10:30 am
day 2  blocked 10:30 am - 11:00 am
day 3: blocked 11:00 am - 11:30 am
and so on

There are no application defined quartz jobs.

We identfied the reason: there is a lock on a databasetable to which the jboss is trying to fire insert queries.
These queries are freezing for exactly 5 minutes and are then rolledback (the transaction time is 5min).

There is no "SELECT FOR UPDATE" or any other explicit locking of the table.
And as the INSERT query is freezing, there are only two options:
1. Some Process/Query is performing an exclusive lock on the table
2. A second query is trying to insert some data with the identical pk in the table (which is fairly unlikely as we use uuid as pk and the hibernate uuid generator)

So No 1 is our next guess. As we (our application) is not doing any locking, are there some jboss internals that are performing cleanups or what ever every every 24 hours?
Same question for postgres. (postgres 9.2 on CentOS, autovacuum is not enabled)

Comment: Doe your application use JMS?

Comment: Yes we use JMS, but also RMI

Comment: Are you using one of your postgresql databases as a backing store for JMS messages?

Comment: No, we have a dedicated hornetq server for this (without a sql backend).
The application has only a MDB as message consumer that listens on a queue.

Comment: I think @SteveC could be on the right track after all. HornetQ does not support database as persistence store (file syste only). However, JBoss AS 5 comes with another JMS implementation, which supports it. Could it be that it has not been disabled and is somehow setup to use your database as persistence store?

Comment: What is the name of the table that is locked? How many JBoss instances are using these databases? BTW, it smells like deadlock to me FWIW

Comment: JBoss 5.x also uses a database table for persisting EJB timers. Have you by any chance changed the DefaultDS to point at one of your Postgresql databases?

Comment: @SteveC the table name is "incident" and i believe it is a deadlock too. The DefaultDS points to a postgresql database, but thats normal configutation@Magnilex i have to check that. If it is not disabled, why could this create a deadlock or freeze of other transactions?

Comment: @martin I don't know. But it could explain the polling of the database.

Comment: I don't know of any standard JBoss AS 5.x components that create an `incident` table. Is this EAP? Do you have a 3rd party monitoring component installed?

Comment: No this is a table of our application, sorry. no 3rd party monitoring. we now have query logging enabled in postgres. maybe this will give us a hint